# How to simulate a mouse click in a datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to simulate a mouse click in my datatables (I'm using Datatables plugin to make the table) when I click on the `Edit` button to open the inline editor in my table. For this I use `$("#datatable td").trigger("click");`, it's work but with this method the inline editor open for each line of the table and I would like to open the inline on the line where the button is and not everywhere.

JS :

```
$("#datatable").on("click", "#btn_ed", function () {
    $("#datatable td").trigger("click");
});
```

[image]

Comment: You should call the logic for when you click the edit button instead, rather than simulating clicking the button, just to call this logic in the long run.

Comment: Just to understand your question better -- why do you need to *simulate* the click after a click has actually occurred?

Comment: @Kobe For the inline editor I'm using a external plugins ([cellEditor](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit))

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Now when I click on a cell include in the 'Surface Area' column I can edit it but for a better UI/UX I add a button edit on each line of te table to edit the cell  'Surface Area' in the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Hope it helps

```
 $("#datatable").on("click", "#btn_ed", function () {

             $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function(e){

                   $(this).trigger('click')  

            })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest` to find the `td` belonging to the button:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.editBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest('td').trigger("click");
});
```

This assumes your edit buttons have the class `editBtn`.

Also take note that I'm using the three-parameter method, which will make the click handler work even when new `td`s are being added later on.

I see you added a code snippet to your question which uses an id to select the edit buttons. This is bad practice, the id of an element should be unique and the selector should apply to only one result. It is better to use a class for all edit buttons.